# PDEs on noncylindrical domains

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Can someone give me some information about this area?

PDEs on non-cylindrical domains I take to mean parabolic (let's fixed parabolic) PDEs on domains which evolve in time.

What is the state of the art on this topic? What kind of problems do people consider? What tools are used for existence and uniqueness? Any recommended papers?